# What's the meaning of "住まい" in "住まいが一番大変" sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation

I would like to ask about "住まい" meaning. I know that "一番大変" is the hardest. And I also search about "住まい" and they said it's "address, home, live, dwelling, residence". But there are no word that suit with "the hardest" and it's no make sense.
Or this is a figurative sentence??

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you provide some context to the sentence?

Comment: hi @istrasci thank you for the response. the context is a sister told to her brother that there is a wisdom behind their parents dying. she proud with their house, and then she said "衣食住の中では住 (dwelling for fullfill necessities), 住まいが一番大変 (.... is the hardest)"

Comment: Just in terms of budgeting, that makes sense to me -- clothing and food are relatively inexpensive, while housing is often the biggest single chunk of anyone's monthly budget (either to pay the rent, or to pay the mortgage).  Does that help make this sentence make sense to you?

Comment: hi @EiríkrÚtlendi thank you for your explanation. Oh, I see. Does it means that i can translate 住まい as manage housing?

Comment: @Renna, 住【す】まい is literally "residence, dwelling, home", as you note.  The "manage" part is not included just in the word 住【す】まい.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi so it's okay if it translated as "dwelling is the hardest" ?

Comment: Without more context, it is difficult to judge what is a "good" translation.  :)  If you're asking about how to render 住【す】まいが一番【いちばん】大変【たいへん】, I might say something like "housing is the biggest issue" or even "affording a roof over my head is the most expensive part".  As an English statement, "dwelling is the hardest" is confusing and unnatural: we just don't use the word "dwelling" that way.

Comment: aah, thank you very much for your suggestion. it helps me a lot @EiríkrÚtlendi

Comment: I'm wondering about the deeper context here too. 衣食住 is a Buddhist concept about the three necessities of life.  Is there perhaps a Buddhist connection in the story?

Comment: @A.Ellett i thought they din't mention about buddhist. The siblings just gather in their house after working and did deep talk about had to thankful for their parents gift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't omit the context and the full sentence. So is this the full sentence you are asking about?

> 衣食住の中では住、住まいが一番大変。

Then it means "Among 衣食住, 住 is the hardest". 衣食住【いしょくじゅう】 is a compound that refers to the three basic necessities in our life (衣 = clothing, 食 = eating, 住 = sheltering/housing/housekeeping).

住まい refers to the same thing as 住 here. Since 住 is a short on-reading which makes little sense in isolation, this person rephrased it as 住まい, which is a wago that means the same thing.

But what this 住 (= 住まい) actually translates to depends on the context. It may refer to buying a new physical house, or it may refer to housekeeping jobs such as cleaning. The sentence may just mean "I like cooking but cleaning my house is a hard task to me".

Comment: Aah, sorry for incomplete sentence. Yeah, she thankful about the house she had. So, she said "衣食住の中では住" , but there are some difficulty in it. Thank you for your explanation, I understand now